# IOS7 crahes on camera

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

My application crashes when running the following on iOS7.
Its was working perfectly fine on iOS6

```
UIImagePickerController *ImagePicker;

@try {
   ImagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]autorelease];
   ImagePicker.sourceType= UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   ImagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
   ImagePicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
   ImagePicker.navigationBarHidden= YES;
   //  ImagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

   ImagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(ImagePicker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM, CAMERA_TRANSFORM);  
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    [ImagePicker release];
    ImagePicker = nil;
}
@finally {

    if(ImagePicker)
    {
        [cameralayer addSubview:[ImagePicker view]];
        [cameralayer release];
    }

}
```

Comment: On what line does the crash occur?  What output (if any) do you see on the console when the crash occurs?

Comment: On Addsubview and at times it just show EXE Bad Comn error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not guaranteeing that `ImagePicker` will be in memory by the time you reach the line that adds it's view to the `cameralayer`.  Don't `autorelease` `ImagePicker` right after you create it.  Only `release` it once you are really done using it and its view.

Comment: When you autorelease an object, it gets released 'at some point in the future' (typically at the end/start of the run loop).  Perhaps that point in time is occurring earlier on iOS7 or maybe you're running on a different device, etc.  Basically, your code is unsafe as written and you should fix it to guarantee that that object lives as long as you need it to.